# Unable to dynamically resize an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resize the icon on the upper left side. I tried to use resize in css but it doesn't change its size when I resized my browser. However, my main image in the middle and all the images on the bottom are able to be resized dynamically. Please give me some advices! Thanks :)

This is the html:

```css
.icon{ 
  display: inline-block; 
  position:absolute;    
     left:0;
     margin-left:8px; 

  }

.icon img{
  max-width: 45%;
  height: auto;
     resize: both;
     vertical-align: center;
     top:0px;
     left:20px;

  }

.header-text{ 
  display: inline-block;
     right:0;
     margin-right:8px;
     position:absolute; 
     height:900px;

      }


#name{color: #707070;

margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 2.2vw;}

#ninja{
 color: #A8A8A8;
 margin-top: 1px;
 font-size: 2vw;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 right:0px;

 }

.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 155px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFCCFF;
 }

#nz{
    position: relative;
    top: 155px;
    left: 7.25px;
 }

#feature{
 position: relative;
    top: 145px;
    left: 7.25px;
 }

#feature h1{
 color: #707070;
 font-size: 3.2vw;
}

table{
 table-layout : fixed
}

#baby-seal{
 margin-top: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 font-size: 3.2vw;
}

#wiki-link{
 margin-top: 1px;
}

#wiki-link a{
 font-size: 2.2vw;
}

.work{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Users/yianlai/Desktop/UDACITY-PROJECT1/project1.css'>
</head>
<body>


   <div class='icon' align='left'>
    <img  src='http://rlv.zcache.ca/kiwi_new_zealand_emblem_sticker-r12b5f18476154510b5c44ff86c3110e5_v9wth_8byvr_324.jpg'>
   </div>
         
         <div class='header-text'>
          <div align='right'id="name"><h1>Baby Seal</h1></div>
       <div align='right' id="ninja">NiNJA</div>
         </div>
            
   <div class="line"></div>

      <div id="nz" align="center"><img src='http://www.wallcoo.net/nature/new_zealand_landscape/images/A%20melting%20glacier%20in%20New%20Zealand.jpg' style="width: 100%"></div>

      <div id="feature">
       <h1>FEATURE WORK</h1>

       <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>
         <td>

          <div class="work">
          <div align="left"><img style="width: 100%" src='http://babyanimalz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/baby-seal-picture.png' ></div>
          <div id="baby-seal"><h1>Baby Seal</h1></div>
          <div id="wiki-link"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal</a></div>
          </div>


         </td>


         <td>

          <div class="work">
          <div align="left"><img style="width: 100%" src='http://babyanimalz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/baby-seal-picture.png' ></div>
          <div id="baby-seal"><h1>Baby Seal</h1></div>
          <div id="wiki-link"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal</a></div>
          </div>


         </td>

         <td>

          <div class="work">
          <div align="left"><img style="width: 100%" src='http://babyanimalz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/baby-seal-picture.png' ></div>
          <div id="baby-seal"><h1>Baby Seal</h1></div>
          <div id="wiki-link"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal</a></div>
          </div>


         </td>
        </tr>


       </table>


      </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add CSS media queries and set the size of the image for each

Comment: I don't think it's re-sizing because it doesn't need to. It will only resize when it doesn't fit in its container `.icon`. If you want it to resize you would have to give a width to `.icon` like `width:18%;` then set the `.icon img` with a `max-width:100%;`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50514jhr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `<img>` from the `.icon` container and set it as the background image.

The updated css for `.icon` would be this:

```
.icon{  
    display: inline-block; 
    position:absolute;    
    left:0;
    margin-left:8px; 
    height:150px;
    width:18%; 
    background:url(http://rlv.zcache.ca/kiwi_new_zealand_emblem_sticker-r12b5f18476154510b5c44ff86c3110e5_v9wth_8byvr_324.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Of course you can set the height and width to whatever you want. This way the icon will resize with the window and always stay in the center.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50514jhr/1/) for a demo. (resize the frame window to see it in action)